# Starting two threads runs them in sequence and not at the same time

Tags: c#

I have a main thread which is controlling a windows form, upon pressing a button two threads are executed. One is used for recording information, the other is used for reading it. The idea behind putting these in threads is to enable the user to interact with the interface while they are executing.

Here is the creating of the two threads;

```
Thread recordThread = new Thread(() => RecordData(data));
recordThread.Name = "record";
recordThread.Start();

Thread readThread = new Thread(() => ReadData(data));
readThread.Name = "read";
readThread.Start();
```

The *data* is simply a Data-object that stores the data that is recorded during the recording.

The problem that I am facing is that the first thread is executed fine, the second refuses to run until the first one completes. Putting a breakpoint in the second threads function, *ReadData* lets me know that it is only called after the first thread is done with all of its recording.

I have been trying to solve this for a few hours now and I can't get my head around why it would do this. Adding a;

```
while(readThread.IsAlive) { }
```

right after the start will halt the execution of anything after that, and it's state is *Running*. But it will not go to the given method.

Any ideas?

**Edit**:
The two functions that are called upon by the threads are;

```
    private void RecordData(Data d)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < time * freq)
        {
            double[] data = daq.Read();
            d.AddData(data);
            i++;
        }
    }

    private void ReadData(Data d)
    {
        UpdateLabelDelegate updateData =
            new UpdateLabelDelegate(UpdateLabel);

        int i = 0;
        while (i < time * freq)
        {
            double[] data = d.ReadLastData();
            this.Invoke(updateData, new object[] { data });
            i++;
        }
    }
```

The *data* object has locking in both the functions that are called upon; *ReadLastData and Read*.

Here are the methods in the *Data* object.

```
    public void AddData(double[] data)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (double d in data)
            {
                movementData[i].Add(d);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public double[] ReadLastData()
    {
        double[] data = new double[channels];
        lock (this)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (List<double> list in movementData)
            {
                data[i] = list[list.Count - 1];
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: It depends if the second thread is waiting on a resource locked by the first thread (guessing `data`). What locking have you got in place?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Please show more code, this is insufficient

Comment: @Belogix AFAIK locking wouldn't block the thread itself from being run. It would, however, block *inside* that thread until the other thread released the object.

Comment: That is what I mean @James, we don't know what he is doing inside the thread (i.e. one will lock the other). I didn't mean it would stop it from even getting going.

Comment: @Belogix the OP was suggesting that the thread itself wasn't being run i.e. "*the second refuses to run until the first one completes. Putting a breakpoint in the second threads function, ReadData lets me know that it is only called after the first thread is done with all of its recording*". Just clarifying as the thread not being *executed* is a different problem to it being *locked*.

Comment: @James - I don't want to hijack the question but he says "Putting a breakpoint in the second threads function, **ReadData lets me know that it is** only called after the first thread is done..." which suggests the thread is running but **ReadData** method is blocked which is INSIDE the thread? I read it that thread starting but first method in thread (i.e. ReadData) is blocked?

Comment: @Belogix - yeah it's an issue with the wording of the question really, the OP says "**the second refuses to run until the first one completes**" suggested to me that the thread itself wouldn't run until the first one had finished executing. Based on the OP's update though it's clearly a blocking problem and the thread is being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a race condition between your reading/writing. In your first thread you lock down the object whilst you add data to it and in the second thread you *attempt* to get an exclusive lock on it to start reading. However, the problem is the first thread is executing so fast that the second thread never really gets a chance to acquire the lock.

The solution to this problem really depends on what sort of behaviour you are after here. If you expect after every write you get a consecutive read then what you need to do is control the execution between the reading/writing operations e.g.

```
static AutoResetEvent canWrite = new AutoResetEvent(true); // default to true so the first write happens
static AutoResetEvent canRead = new AutoResetEvent(false);
...
private void RecordData(Data d)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < time * freq)
    {
        double[] data = daq.Read();
        canWrite.WaitOne(); // wait for the second thread to finish reading
        d.AddData(data);
        canRead.Set(); // let the second thread know we have finished writing
        i++;
    }
}

private void ReadData(Data d)
{
    UpdateLabelDelegate updateData =
        new UpdateLabelDelegate(UpdateLabel);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < time * freq)
    {
        canRead.WaitOne(); // wait for the first thread to finish writing
        double[] data = d.ReadLastData();
        canWrite.Set(); // let the first thread know we have finished reading
        this.Invoke(updateData, new object[] { data });
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to have solved the issue of the firing of the functions! Nice! The only trouble was that this causes my system to not function properly due to that it is now too slow. I will start testing with it reading every tenth value or so. But that is another issue, this is the solution to this question. Thanks!

Comment: @Sander what exactly is it you need to happen? Do you *really* need the read to happen during the write? Just an FYI on your usage of the [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.80).aspx) - it's not recommended to lock types themselves i.e. `lock(this)` violates the guidelines. You should instead have a locking object external to your *data* instance (similar to how I am using the `AutoResetEvent` in my example). You might actually find that's what the underlying problem is here.

Comment: Having changed the code to what you recommended it did work, as I stated before, only it is too slow. What I wish to do is to get data in realtime from a data acquisition card and present it to the user. That is why I wish to read the data during the write. The information that I get from the record is more important than the read through, so I have to figure out how I should prioritize the record over the read.

Comment: @Sander - What if you revert back to your original code but instead of locking `data` internally you lock it externally in both your `RecordData`/`ReadData` methods? If you need to print the data as it comes in couldn't you just handle the `UpdateLabelDelegate` from inside the write? So effectively you are doing the reading/writing within the same operation.

Comment: I did try that before, but the acquisition was too slow. Having gone back and reviewed it again it seems the issue was not the thread running too slow but that I was getting one value at a time from the hardware. Changing THAT to 50 values increased the performance dramatically. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding a Sleep inside RecordData?
Maybe it's just your (mono cpu??) windows operating system that doesn't let the second thread get its hand on cpu resources.

Don't do this:
    lock (this)

Do something like this instead:

```
private object oLock = new object();

[...]

lock (this.oLock)
```

EDIT:
Could you try calls like this:

```
Thread recordThread = new Thread((o) => RecordData((Data)o));
recordThread.Name = "record";
recordThread.Start(data);
```

Comment: I am running a system with 4 cores. And as to my understanding multiple threads should be able to run even on a single core. But anyways, in my case that should really *not* be an issue. (Edit: forgot the "not")

Comment: event with the oLock change? : /

Comment: Yes. The problem seems to be related to the threads and not the data-object. If I set a breakpoint just *before* it runs the ReadData method, it will not get triggered until the first thread has completed its run.

Comment: @Sander the issue *is* to do with the data object, not the threads. You are locking it down as you perform your add and not giving the second thread a chance to get a lock on it to perform reading.

Comment: @James I noticed now that all the updates from the second thread (Read) are done once the first one is completed, i.e the UI updates all come once the first thread is done. This may have something to do with the invoke rather than the threads. I will have to continue reading about invokes/delegates and see if this could be the crook.

Comment: @Sander All Invoke does is force the call onto the UI thread, from what I am seeing you have a race condition, see my answer.